# Fully-connected layer weight dimensions in TensorFlow ConvNet

Tags: convolution, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I've been coding along [this example](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/3%20-%20Neural%20Networks/convolutional_network.ipynb) of a convolution net in TensorFlow and I'm mystified by this allocation of weights:

```
weights = {

# 5x5 conv, 1 input, 32 outputs
'wc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 1, 32])),

# 5x5 conv, 32 inputs, 64 outputs
'wc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 32, 64])), 

# fully connected, 7*7*64 inputs, 1024 outputs
'wd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([7*7*64, 1024])), 

# 1024 inputs, 10 outputs (class prediction)
'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, n_classes])) 

}
```

**How do we know the 'wd1' weight matrix should have 7 x 7 x 64 rows?**

It's later used to reshape the output of the second convolution layer:

```
# Fully connected layer
# Reshape conv2 output to fit dense layer input
dense1 = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, _weights['wd1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]]) 

# Relu activation
dense1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(dense1, _weights['wd1']), _biases['bd1']))
```

By my math, pooling layer 2 (conv2 output) has 4 x 4 x 64 neurons.

**Why are we reshaping to [-1, 7*7*64]?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Working from the start:

The input, `_X` is of size `[28x28x1]` (ignoring the batch dimension).  A 28x28 greyscale image.

The first convolutional layer uses `PADDING=same`, so it outputs a 28x28 layer, which is then passed to a `max_pool` with `k=2`, which reduces each dimension by a factor of two, resulting in a 14x14 spatial layout.  conv1 has 32 outputs -- so the full per-example tensor is now `[14x14x32]`.

This is repeated in `conv2`, which has 64 outputs, resulting in a `[7x7x64]`.

tl;dr:  The image starts as 28x28, and each maxpool reduces it by a factor of two in each dimension.  28/2/2 = 7.

Comment: You just resolved a terrible misunderstanding I had about the dimensionality of the layers. Completely ignored `PADDING=same` and was foreseeably confused. Thank you!!

Comment: Why is `_X` of dimension `[28x28x1]`? Shouldn't it be `[28x28]`? Why the extra `x1`?

Comment: The convolution operators expect a batch where entries have height, width, and depth.  The last x1 is just a cosmetic reshape.

Comment: In [this](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3%20-%20Neural%20Networks/alexnet.py) example, there are 3 conv layers, and 2 fully connected ones. The strides of conv layer is 1 and pool layer is 2. Thus following the same logic, shouldn't the size of 3rd conv layer be 7/2, rather than 4 as given in the code?

Comment: What happens when it comes to multi-channel data? (e.g. RGB images)

Answer (score 1):

This question requires you have a good understanding of deep learning convolutions.

Basically, each convolution layer your model has will reduce the convolutional pyramid transversal area. This reduction is made by the **convolution stride** and **max_pooling stride**. And to complicate things we have two options based on the PADDING.

Option 1 - `PADDING='SAME'`

```
out_height = ceil(float(in_height) / float(strides[1]))
out_width  = ceil(float(in_width) / float(strides[2]))
```

Option 2 - `PADDING='VALID'`

```
out_height = ceil(float(in_height - filter_height + 1) / float(strides[1]))
out_width  = ceil(float(in_width - filter_width + 1) / float(strides[2]))
```

For **EACH** convolution and max pooling call you will have to calculate a new `out_height` and `out_width`. Then, in the end of the convolutions you multiply `out_height`, `out_width` and the **depth** of your last convolution layer. The result of this multiplication is the output feature map size which is the input of your first fully connected layer.

So, in your example you probably had only `PADDING='SAME'`, a convolution stride of 1 and a max pooling stride of 2, **twice**. In the end you just had to divide everything by 4 (1,2,1,2).

More info at [tensorflow API](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/nn.html#convolution)